# Finding which partition on a particular disk is active from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, partitioning

For example, if I'm booted from Windows PE, or remoting into a system using psexec or another command-line based method.  I know that `diskpart.exe` allows you to set the active partition, but I can't find any way of seeing which partition is currently active.

Hopefully there's a simple answer and I'm just missing it ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Only way I know how to do this is close to what @Maximus put but do the following:

```
diskpart.exe
select volume 1
detail partition
```

The output will indicate

```
Active: Yes/No
```

For example:
[image]

You have to go through each volume to find which ones are Active and which ones are not. You can use Diskpart's `list volume` command to show all volumes and find the one you want to check first.

Comment: Note this only works for [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) disks, but fails for [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) disks as there the concept of "active" is not part of the partition but of the [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Configuration_Data).

Answer (score 10):

You can use `wmic` to do this. You may wish to export it to a text file (`>output.txt`) and view without word wrapping since the tabular output can get very wide.

To list all partitions (look at the `BootPartition` member to check if it's marked as `active`):

```
wmic partition
```

To list just active partitions, filter with `where`:

```
wmic partition where BootPartition=true
```

To filter which columns are displayed, use `get`:

```
wmic partition where BootPartition=true get DeviceID,Size
```

Also:

```
wmic partition get DeviceID,Size,BootPartition
```

For more information on `partition` members, see [the Win32_DiskPartition documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> **BootPartition**
>
> Data type: boolean
>   Access type: Read-only
>
> Partition is the active partition. The operating system uses the active partition when booting from a hard disk.

---

Take a look at [the WQL syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information on the usage of `where`. Take a look at `wmic partition get /?` for more information on `get`.

---

With `wmic` you have added advantages with remote management using the `/node:<servername or ip>` switch (see `wmic /node /?` for more information. As per [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wmic_overview.mspx?mfr=true):

> WMIC can be used from any computer with WMIC enabled to remotely manage any computer with WMI. WMIC does not have to be available on the remotely managed computer in order for WMIC to manage it.

---

If you can figure out some way of programmatically (e.g. batch script) getting the drive letter from the disk and partition index, you may wish to use a `for` loop with the members `DiskIndex` and `Index` (disk and partition indexes, respectively).

Answer (score 3):

```
select disk 0
detail disk
```

Look into last column (System)?

Comment: What if it is not a system disk; how can you tell if the partition is active? For example, if you have a second disk with a FAT32 partition from which XP is dual-booted, does it say *System*?

Comment: I thought at first this was the correct answer, but it turns out that this only shows which partition the running instance of Windows was booted from.  If the active partition has changed since then, or if you are booted from removable media, it doesn't work.

Comment: But how about asterisk in `detail disk` (first column)? May be it is the answer?

Comment: No, the asterisk shows you which volume (if any) is currently selected (SELECT VOLUME or SELECT PARTITION).

Answer (score 2):

As a fans of [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com), I'll suggest use the [fdisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdisk) utility from the [util-linux](http://cygwin.com/packages/util-linux) package to do this **if you're not using [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)**.

If you're remoting into a system, you need to install Cygwin on that system.

If you're booting from Windows PE, you can manually download the packages and extract them using a proper decompressor which can handle .tar.bz2 files.

**Packages needed to download to run fdisk**

- [util-linux](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/release/util-linux)
- [util-linux/libblkid1](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/release/util-linux/libblkid1)
- [util-linux/libuuid1](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/release/util-linux/libuuid1)
- [cygwin](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/release/cygwin)
- [libiconv/libiconv2](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/release/libiconv/libiconv2)
- [gettext/libintl8](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/release/gettext/libintl8)
- [gcc4/libgcc1](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/release/gcc4/libgcc1)

**Example (1 hdd, 1 flash drive)**

```
$ uname -svr
CYGWIN_NT-5.1 1.7.17(0.262/5/3) 2012-10-19 14:39

$ /usr/sbin/fdisk -l | grep /dev/
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
/dev/sda1   *          63    83891429    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        83891430   625137344   270622957+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        83891493   503332514   209720511    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       503332578   625137344    60902383+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk /dev/sdb: 8065 MB, 8065646080 bytes
/dev/sdb1   *          32    15753214     7876591+   b  W95 FAT32
```